# The dreaded apocalyptic asteroid approaches Earth but lands 'safely' on the Moon

Tags: orbital-mechanics

**NOTE- PLEASE DON'T ANSWER HERE. I'M DELETING HERE AND MOVING TO SPACE EXPLORATION SE.**  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32411/the-dreaded-apocalyptic-asteroid-approaches-earth-but-lands-safely-on-the-moon

**AT THE MOMENT I AM UNABLE TO DELETE - THE MODS HAVE BEEN ALERTED**

An asteroid approaches and the Moon 'catches' it in the same way that a sports player catches a ball - that is to say by matching the velocity of the hand to that of the ball.

Could a lucky slingshot approach cause this to happen?

Assuming that the Moon has no atmosphere, my intuition tells me that there must be a direction and velocity such that an asteroid can do this. Does mathematics say otherwise?

> In orbital mechanics and aerospace engineering, a gravitational
>   slingshot, gravity assist maneuver, or swing-by is the use of the
>   relative movement (e.g. orbit around the Sun) and gravity of a planet
>   or other astronomical object to alter the path and speed of a
>   spacecraft
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist

Comment: See it this way: since there are no aerodynamics involved, the whole process is entirely reversible. So you have to imagine an asteroid sitting quietly on the Moon's surface, then suddenly taking off and disappearing into deep space, just like that. Clearly this is **not** something you can imagine, and therefore the reverse is also not possible. Your best bet is that the asteroid comes in at a very shallow angle to the Moon, scrapes along its surface for a while, and eventually [skip-stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_skipping) to a halt without too much damage to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author has already decided to move the question.

Comment: I have voted to close my own question. I'm getting a note saying I can't delete. I'm now stuck with both questions open. This has been reported to the mods  by Mołot so hopefully it will get resolved. Apologies to all.– chasly from UK 22 mins ago

Comment: I've closed the question here for you @chaslyfromUK

Comment: It needs to be a very slow moving asteroid. and moving in precisely the right vector. That's the hardest part of your question as if getting the velocities right isn't hard enough.

Answer (score 3):

There is a gravity interaction between Moon and asteroid. It is the same interaction that prevents things from flying away. Thus, for an object falling on the Moon, minimal possible speed of impact is the same as [Moon escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#List_of_escape_velocities), roughly 2.38 km/s

Gravity assist works, because speed is increased when getting closer to the planet. You can use Mars to slow down something in relation to Earth or sun, but you cannot use it to slow it down in relation to Mars.

Comment: Hi, Apologies. I'm deleting and moving to Space Exploration. Please feel free to answer over there. I understand what you are saying but I'm not convinced - that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK don't say you are deleting. Delete, or do not delete. As for space exploration, I'm pretty sure something similar was already asked, so be sure to search before you ask.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Also, astronomy stack seems to say the same about impact / escape velocity. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20806

Comment: I'm getting a note saying I can't delete. I'm now stuck with both questions open.

Comment: I have flagged for diamond moderator attention, they can do more than we.

Comment: @ Mołot Mind you , that's for Earth. I imagine the atmosphere is going to change things.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK atmosphere is only going to slow impact down.